# Can't visualize nodes in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to change my visualization script to be more like the [Modifying a Force Layout Example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795). Since I don't have fixed nodes like `a, b and c` to add I read a `json file` to fill the `nodes` and `links` array.

```
d3.json("mock.json", function(error, json) {
    if (error)
        throw error;
    nodes = nodes.concat(json.nodes);
    links = links.concat(json.links);
    start();
});
```

`nodes` and `links` have the right size, meaning nodes contains `26 nodes` and links `37 links`. Now I want to simply visualize them using `line` and `circle` elements.

```
function start() {
    link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
    link.enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");
    link.exit().remove();

    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
    node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 8);
    node.exit().remove();
    force.start();
}
```

This is very simular to the example and I don't really understand why this won't work. I provide [a demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/63wrSbzJFx88VhiutmOm?p=preview) with the mock. Is there an issue because I use `concat()` and not `push()` or is there anything else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
d3.json("mock.json", function(error, json) {

    if (error)
        throw error;
    nodes = nodes.concat(json.nodes);
    links = links.concat(json.links);
    start();
});
```

Had to be like this (**reason** else `force.nodes()` will be empty array set initially):

```
d3.json("mock.json", function(error, json) {

    if (error)
        throw error;
    nodes = nodes.concat(json.nodes);
    links = links.concat(json.links);

    force.nodes(nodes); //else force.nodes() will be empty array set initially
    force.links(links)

    start();
});
```

**Next**:

Your Code:

```
link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
```

Corrected code:

```
link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source + "-" + d.target; });
```

Working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/e7XxUN08L8fWsW1MmTln?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jup, works now, but why do I have to use`force.nodes(nodes);`? In the example it works without it, eventhough I wondered how he made the force know about the nodes and links.

Comment: yes because `nodes.concat(json.nodes)` will return a new object while `force.nodes()` will be holding to the old object..so when you do force.nodes() in your code it returns an empty array that is the reason why you don't see anything.

Comment: Thank you! :) Now it makes sense to me. `push()` in this case didn't work for me because it would only push the array inside the other array.

Comment: yes after push you will need to flatten it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript